# What are Equivalence Relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have partially understood [Equivalence Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). Can someone please give me an example ?

Like, all the possible equivalence relations given a set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: The number of equivalence relations on a four-element set is the fourth Bell number, and that's too big for me to want to write down all those relations.

Comment: $15$ is too big for me...

Comment: Do you think that you're going to understand something new by looking at 15 separate partitions of a set? What *exactly* is it that you would like to know about equivalence relations?

Comment: No, I have got (in the answers below) what I required.

Comment: An equivalence relation is a partition of a set.

Answer (score 3):

An equivalence relation is a relation that is:

1) reflexive

2) symmetric

3) transitive

A simple example would be family relations.

I'm related to myself, so it's reflexive.

If I am related to someone then he is related to me, so it's symmetric.

If I am related to A and A is related to B, then I am also related to B, so it's transitive.

the number of equivalence relations on a set is called Bell's number, and it is huge.

I'll give one such example on your set though: $\{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (1, 3), (3, 1)\}$

Comment: Oh okay. I got you.  So that means the minimum number of elements of such a set is 4 which is $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$. And the max number of elements can be $10$ which is the one you mentioned. Right?

Comment: No, not at all. The maximum number of elements in the relation is where everyone is related to everyone. If I am not mistaken that set will have (in your case) $16$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few (though not all 15):

$R_1 = \{<1,1>,<2,2>,<3,3>,<4,4> \}$

$R_2 = \{<1,1>,<1,2>,<2,1>,<2,2>,<3,3>,<4,4> \}$

$R_3 = \{<1,1>,<1,2>,<2,1>,<2,2>,<1,3><3,1>,<2,3><3,2>,<3,3>,<4,4> \}$

These are all equivalence relations, in that they are:

1) reflexive, i.e. for any $x \in A$, $<x,x> \in R$

2) symmetric, i.e for any $a,b \in A$: If $<a,b> \in R$ then $<b,a> \in R$

E.g. for $R_2$ we have $<1,2> \in R_2$, but we also have $<2,1> \in R_2$

Note that $R_1$ does not have any $<a,b>$ with $a \not = b$, but that makes it trivially symmetric!

3) transitive, i.e for any $a,b,c \in A$: If $<a,b> \in R$ and $<b,c> \in R$ then $<a,c> \in R$

E.g for $R_3$ we have $<1,2> \in R_3$ and $<2,3> \in R_3$ and we also have $<1,3> \in R_3$

Note that again $R_1$ is trivially transitive.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Rick Joker says.

If you can partition a set, you have created an equivalence relation.  All members of the set inside each partition form one equivalence class.

For example the set $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ could be partitioned into the even numbers and the odd numbers and that would form an equivalence relation.

Or you could partition $A$ into the "big numbers" $\{3,4\}$ and the little numbers $\{1,2\}$ and that would also be an equivalence relation.

And there is no reason why you couldn't prartion $A$ as $\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4\}$